# Can't open port 8443 in Windows 10

Tags: ssl, tomcat, ssl-certificate, port, windows-firewall

I am trying to verify if the client certificate (self-signed) which I generated with `openssl` is valid. I have created client certificate, client private key, client keystore, and server certificate, server private key, server keystore and server truststore.

I am trying to use the generated server key and certificate in Tomcat by putting the following in server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8443"
    maxThreads="150"
    scheme="https"
    secure="true"
    SSLEnabled="true"
    truststoreFile="C:\New keys\Server\truststore.jks"
    truststorePass="......"
    keystoreFile="C:\New keys\Server\keystore_server"
    keystorePass="......."
    clientAuth="true"
    keyAlias="......."
    sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

I have also added client certificate in Google Chrome.

But when I try to visit `http://localhost:8443/` I get the error `localhost refused to connect`.
I added an inbound rule windows firewall to allow port 8443, yet, after doing this, when I test whether the port is open or closed with online tools, it shows that port 8443 is closed.

How do I open this port? Or is there anything else I can do to solve this?

Comment: Check Tomcat's logs (`catalina.2021-08-02.log` most notably) to see if the connector was successfully initialized.

Comment: Couldn't find "8443" anywhere in catalina.2021-08-02.log

Comment: Does this mean my connector didn't initialize successfully?

Comment: There should be a `Starting ProtocolHandler [https...` line in the logs (at an `INFO` level). If it is not there, check whether your configuration is not commented out by chance. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60427396/11748454) for an example of log entries.

Comment: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind,
This exception is there.

Comment: @SparshDutta Your Tomcat is already running. Make sure it's totally stopped before trying to start it. (It's also possible another process is bound to 8443, but usually the problem is that Tomcat is already running.)